# SQL Join Table with multiple common columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Here are my sample tables, I need help on how can I retrieve them properly as shown.

```
Table_1                    Table_2
| Im_ID | Im_Name |        | Im_ID | S_Im_ID |
|  001  |   ABC   |        |  001  |   004   |
|  002  |   XYZ   |        |  002  |   005   |
|  003  |   PQR   |        |  003  |   006   |
|  004  |   STU   |
|  005  |   DEF   |
|  006  |   JKL   |
```

I want the result like this:

```
Result
| Im_ID | S_Im_ID | Im_Name | S_Im_Name |
|  001  |   004   |   ABC   |    STU    |
|  002  |   005   |   XYZ   |    DEF    |
|  003  |   006   |   PQR   |    JKL    |
```

I am not able to understand how to get names for both im_id and s_im_id. I can do it for just one of the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That requires two `JOIN` operations using the junction table `Table_2` so as to join `Table_1` to itself:

```
SELECT t1.Im_ID, t3.Im_ID AS S_Im_ID, t1.Im_Name, t3.Im_Name AS S_Im_Name
FROM Table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS t2 ON t1.Im_ID = t2.Im_ID
INNER JOIN Table_1 AS t3 ON t2.S_Im_ID = t3.Im_ID
```